# bootstrap + 3 column layout like evernote or asana

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application (SPA). Pretty new to bootstrap but would like to utilize that for creating the layout. Any recommendations for bootstrap themes available for 3 column layout like Evernote or Asana?

I have searched quite a few sites and only seem to find mostly one page front end designs or two column templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anastacio for your reply.

Found one good one here - http://themeforest.net/item/first-mobile-first-web-app-theme/full_screen_preview/5002403

Answer (score 0):

I dont know any layouts for bootstrap, but you could do something like this.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="col1"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" id="col2"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" id="col3"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

or you can use something like this
https://www.boottheme.com